# Access many to one Entity Framework model properties in RenderAction view using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, renderaction

I tried to access the property of model (`FilePath`) in my `Render` action, but without success.

I have these models:

```
public class Offer
{
 public int OfferID { get; set; }
 public string Reference { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
}

public class FilePath
{
 public int FilePathId { get; set; }
 public string FileName { get; set; }
 public virtual Offer Offer { get; set; }
}
```

In controller offer:

```
public PartialViewResult Category()
{
 var offers = db.Offers
 .Include(i => i.FilePaths)
 // i tried with .Include(“FilePaths”) with no sucess
 .ToList();
  return PartialView("_OfferBoxList", offers);
}
```

Showing with:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Category", "Offer");}
```

The problem is in partial action view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 @item.Title // This work
 @item.FilePath.FileName // This NOT work
}
```

Output error:

> 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Offer_278BF6A1F89FB9514329AC922E992AEBD19368D66A4460B6BEBA1BB2256CAFC3' does not contain a definition for 'FilePath'

Thanks for help.

Comment: if you turn off lazy loading, I think it will resolve to the type, instead of the proxy.. however, you should really not be loading your entities into views.. I generally create DTOs for not only shaping the data in a query, but also to use as dataItems/dataSource for these purposes..

Comment: also, `FilePaths` (plural) is the property of `Offer`, and it is a `Collection<FilePath>`.. `@item.FilePath` (singular) doesn't even exist is this code snippet..

Answer (score 2):

Each `Offer` has a list of `FilePath` instances (`ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths`), so you can't just access the `Offer.FilePath.FileName` property, you have to get for instance the first one (depending on what you need), using something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @item.Title // This work
     @item.FilePaths.First().FileName // Take the first FilePath object from the collection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really not be loading your entities into views..

I generally create Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) for a multitude of purposes. Not only does it help me shape the query expression (`IQueryable<T>`), but I also use so that I have concert types (instead of generated dynamic proxy class types - like the type you're seeing in your runtime exception) in control properties, like `dataItem` and `dataSource`, which are often used in runtime bindable dynamic/reflective controls (grids, listviews)..

***Note***
*It is possible to disable the generated dynamic proxy types by declaring and passing your own `DbContextConfiguration` instance to EntityFramework; However, doing so will affect EntityFramework supporting features.*

---

```
public class OfferDTO
{
    public int OfferID { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> FileNames { get; set; }
}
```

you controller function would then look like:

```
public PartialViewResult Category()
{
    var offers = db.Offers.Select<Offer, OfferDTO>( (entity) => new OfferDTO() {
        OfferID = entity.OfferID,
        Reference = entity.Reference,
        Title = entity.Title,
        FileNames = entity.FilePaths.Select<FilePath, string>( filePath => filePath.FileName).AsEnumerable()
    });

    return PartialView("_OfferBoxList", offers.ToList());
}
```

then,

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Category", "OfferDTO");}

@foreach (var item in Model) // Model is IEnumerable<OfferDTO>
{
    @item.Title 
    @item.FileNames.First()
}
```

---

#### Additionally,

you can create an `IQueryable<IQueryable<TEntityDTO>>` to suit your purposes and perform a SelectMany on it to flatten the results.

```
public class OfferTitleFilenameDTO
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Filename {get;set;}
}

public PartialViewResult Category()
{
    var offers = db.Offers.Select<Offer, IQueryable<OfferTitleFilenameDTO>>( (entity) => entity.FilePaths.Select<FilePath, OfferTitleFilenameDTO>(filePath => new OfferTitleFilenameDTO() {
            Filename = filePath.FileName,
            Title = entity.Title
        })
    });

    return PartialView("_OfferBoxList", offers.SelectMany(dtos => dtos));
}
```

then,

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Category", "OfferTitleFilenameDTO");}

@foreach (var item in Model) // Model is IEnumerable<OfferTitleFilenameDTO>
{
    @item.Title 
    @item.Filename 
}
```

Comment: your include statement seems unnecessary here.. ,  I think, in general, that you use includes when you're attempting to specify a query path from other query paths.. and since you only have 1 navigation property.. you only have 1 query path on Offer..

Comment: these samples presumes that `db.Offers` is `IQueryable<Offer>`